# (Python, Keras) Why is my predicted value not near the real value?

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, tensor

I am very new to neural networks. And I'm learning some basics and I'm stuck at this point.

I have played with many parameters included the inital values of the dynamic system. I dropped the learning rate and changed the number of epoches and the batch size. Also I changed the number of samples I give to the fit function. I added a hidden layer and removed one again. After all nothing really helped. Sometimes the predicted value is pretty close and sometimes its really far away from the tested value. Do I miss something? Or how can I improve neural networks in general to get what I want to predict? Do I have to find a "sweet spot"?

Below you can find my code. I would be glad for new ideas to improve the network. I am a beginner and this is my first StackOverflow post.

```
######################### import stuff ##########################
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as p
from keras import backend as K


###Model
k_dim =1000 # Number of timestamps
seq_dim = 1000 # Number of samples

def g_func(x):
    return np.power(x,2)

input1 = keras.Input(shape=(k_dim,))
input2 = keras.Input(shape=(k_dim,))

merged = layers.concatenate([input1,input2])
alpha_pred = layers.Dense(32,input_dim=2, activation='relu')(merged)
x = layers.Dense(16,activation='sigmoid')(alpha_pred)
output_a = layers.Dense(1)(x)
model = keras.Model(inputs=[input1,input2], outputs=output_a)

model.compile(loss='mean_absolute_error', optimizer='sgd', metrics=['mean_squared_error'])
model.summary()


######################## Simulating Input and Output data ########################
n = 2
alpha = np.random.rand(1,seq_dim)
m = 1
X_train = np.random.rand(seq_dim,k_dim)
X_train[:,0] = 0
u = [float] * seq_dim
y_train = np.zeros((seq_dim,k_dim))

for j in range (seq_dim):
    u = X_train[j,:]
    for k in range(k_dim-1):
        for i in range(n-1):
            y_train[j,k+1] = alpha[0,i] * y_train[j, k-i] + g_func(u[k])

alpha = np.transpose(alpha)
print('Learning rate before first fit:', model.optimizer.learning_rate.numpy())
history = model.fit([X_train,y_train], alpha, batch_size=64, epochs=3000)

print("Learning rate before second fit:", model.optimizer.learning_rate.numpy())
K.set_value(model.optimizer.learning_rate, 0.001)
history = model.fit([X_train,y_train], alpha, batch_size=64, epochs=1000)

# Plot the lossfunction and mean squared error
p.plot(history.history['loss'], 'b-', label='LOSS')
p.plot(history.history['mean_squared_error'], 'r-', label='Mean squared error')
p.legend(loc='best')
p.draw()
print('Model trained...')
time.sleep(2)
alpha = None
X_train = None
y_train = None
u = None
seq_dim = 1


#####
###Model has been trained. Lets test with new x and y to get one alpha###
####
X_train = np.random.rand(seq_dim,k_dim)
u = [float] * seq_dim
y_train = np.zeros((seq_dim,k_dim))
alpha = np.array([0.9])

for j in range (seq_dim):
    u = X_train[j, :]
    for k in range(k_dim-1):
        for i in range(n-1):
            y_train[j,k+1] = alpha[i] * y_train[j,k-i] + g_func(u[k])

z = model.predict([X_train, y_train])


#Compare the real value with the predicted value
print('Comparing real value with predicted value')
for i,j in zip(alpha,z):
    print('{} => {}'.format(i,j))

p.show()
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be using sigmoid. This causes vanishing gradients too often and explodes gradients sometimes while backpropogating because its derivates are in range 0-0.25.

You have to know how your data is spread using plot. Also remove outliers in regression problems.

If the input data is too spread in your plot then the model will not predict close to the correct value all the time.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I changed it to relu only now and I had a "mistake" in my inputdata. I sorted my X_train array in a order from small to big now. But the loss is always stuck at around 0.08.. so its not really working. My input data is basically from 0-1. So it is not spread that much is it? Should I change it to a larger interval?

Comment: Neural networks need input in a normalized manner. Dont change your interval. Dont order train data because it will affect the learning of model. The train data must be randomly sent. Regression models rarely have low mse. Plot scatter plot of your data and you will have an idea about why there is always a difference in predictions.

Comment: So the plot shows me that the input and output is really distributed. It dosen't look like a continous function in the range of 0 to 1. What can I do to improve my predictions? Sorry I am pretty new to this type of problems. But thanks for any little help.

Comment: If your continous data is distributed too much then no algorithm can predict with very low mse. You have to understand how the models work